# How to get data using two firestore queries in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks, react-query

In my firestore database i have referenced the Zutaten collection inside the Meal collection.
Now i try to display the data from the Zutaten collection inside my list component.
The `console.log('ingredient data: ', documentSnapshot.data())` statement inside my second snapshot works properly an displays the data from the Zutaten collection.
But i can't access the data outside the useEffect function, so i think i made a mistake with react-hooks.
My code:

```js
function Meal() {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [meal, setMeal] = useState([]); // Initial empty array of meal
  const [ingredient, setIngredient] =  useState([]);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const subscriber = firestore()
      .collection('Meal')
      .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
        const meal = [];
        querySnapshot.forEach(documentSnapshot => {
          meal.push({
            ...documentSnapshot.data(),
            //key: documentSnapshot.id,
        });
          const ingredient = [];
          for (let i=0; i<documentSnapshot.data().Zutaten.length; i++) {
            documentSnapshot.data().Zutaten[i].get().then(documentSnapshot => {
              if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
                console.log('ingredient data: ', documentSnapshot.data())
                ingredient.push({
                  ...documentSnapshot.data(),
                  //key: documentSnapshot.data().id,
                });
              };
            })
            setIngredient(ingredient);
          }
      });
      setMeal(meal);
      setLoading(false);
    });

    // Unsubscribe from events when no longer in use
    return () => subscriber();
  }, []);

  console.log('this is it: ', ingredient);
  

  if (loading) {
    return <ActivityIndicator />;
  }

  return (
    <List
      style={styles.container}
      contentContainerStyle={styles.contentContainer}
      data={meal}
      renderItem={({ item }) => (
        <Card style={styles.item}>
          <Text style={styles.title}> {item.Name}  </Text>
          <Layout>
            <Image
              style={{ height: 128, borderRadius: 5, borderWidth: 2, borderColor: 'black', marginHorizontal: -20 }}
              source={{ uri: item.srcImage}}
            />
          </Layout>
        </Card>
      )}
    />
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually working as expected. Since all data is loaded from Firestore asynchronously, it is only available in the callback. So your calls to `setMeal` and `setLoading` will need to happen inside that callback.

The simplest way to do that is to call `setMeal` inside the loop like this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const subscriber = firestore()
      .collection('Meal')
      .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
        const meal = [];
        querySnapshot.forEach(documentSnapshot => {
          meal.push({
            ...documentSnapshot.data(),
            //key: documentSnapshot.id,
          });
          setMeal(meal); // this is moved
          const ingredient = [];
          for (let i=0; i<documentSnapshot.data().Zutaten.length; i++) {
            documentSnapshot.data().Zutaten[i].get().then(documentSnapshot => {
              if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
                console.log('ingredient data: ', documentSnapshot.data())
                ingredient.push({
                  ...documentSnapshot.data(),
                  //key: documentSnapshot.data().id,
                });
              };
            })
            setIngredient(ingredient);
          }
      });
      setLoading(false);
    });
```

With this code you now render the meal each time you add an entry to it.

---

**Update**: if you're also rendering the ingredients (I didn't see that in the code you shared), you will need to set that to the state inside the callback where you load the ingredients.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const subscriber = firestore()
      .collection('Meal')
      .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
        const meal = [];
        querySnapshot.forEach(documentSnapshot => {
          meal.push({
            ...documentSnapshot.data(),
            //key: documentSnapshot.id,
          });
          setMeal(meal); // this is moved
          const ingredient = [];
          for (let i=0; i<documentSnapshot.data().Zutaten.length; i++) {
            documentSnapshot.data().Zutaten[i].get().then(documentSnapshot => {
              if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
                console.log('ingredient data: ', documentSnapshot.data())
                ingredient.push({
                  ...documentSnapshot.data(),
                  //key: documentSnapshot.data().id,
                });
              };
              setIngredient(ingredient); // move this too
            })
          }
      });
      setLoading(false);
    });
```

Comment: thanks for your fast answer. I can display the data from the meal collection, but i still can't display the data from the ingredient collection in my return statement. I tried `data={meal.concat(ingredient)}`. But if i call it with `<Button onPress={()=> console.log(item.nutrition)}> Button </Button>` it is undefined. it is probalby a obvious mistake

Comment: You can't **return** things that are loaded asynchronously. So if you're also rendering the ingredients (I didn't see that in the code you shared), you will need to set that to the state **inside** the callback where you load the ingredients. I added another snippet to show how you could do that.